# WooCommerce does not redirect to internal link after purchase

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hook

I want to redirect to custom page after purchase on woocommerce code below:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
   global $wp;

   if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_page_by_title( About )->ID );
        exit;
    }
}
```

It redirects to 'order-received' page which does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot th little `""` around the title and you should need to use **`get_permalink()`** function too this way:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
   global $wp;

   if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( "About" )->ID ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

I have tested it and this should work now

Comment: works fine when checkout page set in woocommerce settings, which means other errors on my end if the checkout page set in header.php with <?php


                    define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
                    echo do_shortcode("[woocommerce_checkout]");

                    ?>